# Rails 3, check if parent object is a new record but from the before_create callback of the child

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3 is there a clean way to check if parent object is a new record but from the before_create callback of the child

```
class Parent
    has_many :children

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end

class Child
  before_create :on_before_create

  def on_before_create
      logger.debug self.parent.new_record?  
      logger.debug self.parent.id
      logger.debug self.parent.id_was
  end
end
```

I only want to execute code in on_before_create if the parent is not a new record
but at the point the child is created the parent record has been inserted into the db and so it has an id, id and id_was both return the same value,
new_record? is actually returning nothing, usually it returns a boolean

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `before_save` rather than `before_create`. You'll need to check for create manually, but the callback is fired before any associated objects are saved.

```
class Parent  < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :children

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :on_before_save

  belongs_to :parent

  def on_before_save
    # Don't run if this is not create.
    return unless self.new_record?

    self.parent.new_record? #=> boolean
  end
end
```

Also, make sure you define the callbacks before the associations, as per the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> In order for inheritance to work for the callback queues, you must specify the callbacks before specifying the associations. Otherwise, you might trigger the loading of a child before the parent has registered the callbacks and they won’t be inherited.

Comment: in my case self.parent.new_record? always returns nil; running on rails 3.1.0